# AutoMapper passing extra arguments while mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I am sucessfully using AutoMapper to convert my business objects to Dtos in all my services, and that works out prettly well.

however i would also like to use automapper, to do the reverse i.e to convert dto to business object, but there is one problem, i need to run some custom logic that has dependency on my EF entity context before mapping

for this i would like to pass my EF context to the map method somehow. I know i can use service locator type pattern to resolve dependency, but i hate introducing magic dependencies, and would like to make everything constructor dependent.

Is it possible to pass my dataContext to AutoMapper while mapping ?

Comment: just in case anyone else runs into this, the solution is in the new 2.0 automapper, here is the author's post for it http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/29/automapper-2-0-nestedchild-containers/ although i cant make it to call my constructor logic ..

Answer (score 2):

A possible way could be something like:

```
using (Context db = new Context())
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<dtos, Ent>()
          .BeforeMap((a, b) => /* and here use db */ )
          ./* mapping rules */;

}
```

Declaring the mapping inside a using of your Countext, it should make the context visible in the BeforeMap(), where you can perform your logics.

Comment: wondering if this would cause some performance issues, since i would essentially endup creating maps for my entire domain model inside every db context creations ?

Comment: Yes, but you can always check the mapping before: Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(dtos), typeof(Ent)) will return null if the mapping doesn't exist

Comment: if i check before and if the mapping exists already, then i wont be able to create the map with in the current context that references the correct instance of db context, right ?

Comment: Do note that this is not thread safe, doing the mapping like this will break in a shared environment like ASP.NET or WCF since different requests will overwrite the same global mapping config.. if you need to do this, you have to stop using the static Mapper and use an instance of IMappingEngine... also do note that if you go down this route, you can pretty much do it all by hand since you will have to handle removes from collections, identity mapping etc manually... AutoMapper just makes this harder